# Does inputtextarea trigger any event after a suggestion is clicked?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have an inputtextarea which calls a completeMethod after a query is entered... that is working fine and the suggestions are displaying, but I woul'd need to catch the ajax event in order to know which suggestion the user has picked. Is it possible?

Comment: At least there is source code present for [handling the itemSelect AJAX event](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/7643be24cf77a5bd5371147408b4db03fe2041d3/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/inputtextarea/InputTextarea.java#L92), but if this does not work, create a [mcve] and file a bug report.

Comment: I've seen the Primefaces code you mention, they generate a SelectItem event from the AjaxBehaviorEvent, but as you say, it's not working, the event is not triggered.

Comment: You have actually found a bug. I filed a [bug report #5071](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5071) and will later add an answer with workaround.

Comment: Bug has been merged and will be in PF 7.1.  If you need it now you will need to build from source or use the jitpack.io version.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the ajax `itemSelect` event like so:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputTextarea widgetVar="textarea" completeMethod="#{myBean.complete}">
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{myBean.onSelect}" />
    </p:inputTextarea>
</h:form>
```

Managed bean methods:

```
public List<String> complete(String filter) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        result.add(filter + i);
    return result;
}

public void onSelect(SelectEvent<String> e) {
    System.out.println(e.getObject());
}
```

This does not work in Primefaces 7.0 (and probably earlier) because the [renderer of the inputTextarea fails](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5071) to add the clientBehavior configuration which is fixed as of Version 7.1.

In the browser javascript console input:

```
PF('textarea').cfg.behaviors
> undefined
```

The result `undefined` indicates missing client behavior configuration.

You can work around this by overriding the InputTextareaRenderer.encodeScript() method:

```
package my.package;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.inputtextarea.InputTextarea;
import org.primefaces.component.inputtextarea.InputTextareaRenderer;
import org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade;
import org.primefaces.util.WidgetBuilder;

public class CustomInputTextareaRenderer extends InputTextareaRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void encodeScript(FacesContext context, InputTextarea inputTextarea) throws IOException {
        String clientId = inputTextarea.getClientId(context);
        boolean autoResize = inputTextarea.isAutoResize();
        String counter = inputTextarea.getCounter();

        WidgetBuilder wb = getWidgetBuilder(context);
        wb.init("InputTextarea", inputTextarea.resolveWidgetVar(), clientId).attr("autoResize", autoResize)
                .attr("maxlength", inputTextarea.getMaxlength(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        if (counter != null) {
            UIComponent counterComponent = SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponent(context, inputTextarea, counter);

            wb.attr("counter", counterComponent.getClientId(context)).attr("counterTemplate",
                    inputTextarea.getCounterTemplate(), null);
        }

        if (inputTextarea.getCompleteMethod() != null) {
            wb.attr("autoComplete", true).attr("minQueryLength", inputTextarea.getMinQueryLength())
                    .attr("queryDelay", inputTextarea.getQueryDelay())
                    .attr("scrollHeight", inputTextarea.getScrollHeight(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        // additional line enabling AJAX 'itemSelect' event handling.
        encodeClientBehaviors(context, inputTextarea);

        wb.finish();
    }
}
```

In faces config, add the renderer:

```
<faces-config>
  ...
  <render-kit>
      <renderer>
          <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
          <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.InputTextareaRenderer</renderer-type>
          <renderer-class>my.package.CustomInputTextareaRenderer</renderer-class>
      </renderer>
  </render-kit>
</faces-config>
```

Quick indication that it works in javascript console:

```
PF('textarea').cfg.behaviors
> Object { itemSelect: itemSelect() }
```

Comment: I tried `PF('...').cfg.behaviors`  on several components in the showcase that have ajax an them but none retured anything other than undefined... Weird

Comment: Ooooops.... I fell into the 'English vs American' trap. `behavior` vs `behaviour` https://grammarist.com/spelling/behavior-behaviour/

Comment: @Kukeltje And my syntax requires a widgetVar, not sure if most showcase components do have one configured? Additionally it only includes very special events like 'itemSelect' but not general oney like 'click', 'change' etc. and only if there is an p:ajax present to catch it.