# What are the possible ajax events for a primefaces InputText?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

What are the possible events that I can have in there? thank you :)

```
 <p:inputText>
    <p:ajax event="" />
 </p:inputText>
```

Tried looking at [List of <p:ajax> events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586779/list-of-pajax-events) but the documentation doesn't have a list of the possible events for each component :p

Comment: @Kukeltje Dude why downvote me, now I won't be able to ask anything... theres no documentation for the ajax event for an inputtext, I only know there is onchange and onblur, but there must be more right :p

Comment: Inddition to the suggedtions above, also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57500617/does-inputtextarea-trigger-any-event-after-a-suggestion-is-clicked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of <p:ajax> events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586779/list-of-pajax-events)

Comment: @Kukeltje I saw that but if you go to the docs where balus says it doesn't have a list of events like the answer in here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Primefaces 7.0 `InputText` extends `HtmlInputText` but does not override `getEventNames()` method, you can find them [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/8687eb916ef39eaae5a9cd4c1e21cdd623b22152/impl/src/main/java/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputText.java#L716).

```
"blur","change","valueChange","click","dblclick","focus","keydown","keypress",
"keyup","mousedown","mousemove","mouseout","mouseover","mouseup","select"
```

In order to easily get all the event names, you can simply use the `javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.getEventNames()` method on a component instance:

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase;

public class SomeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dumpEvents(new org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText());
        dumpEvents(new org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete());
        dumpEvents(new org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable());
    }

    private static void dumpEvents(UIComponentBase comp) {
        System.out.println(
                comp + ":\n\tdefaultEvent: " + comp.getDefaultEventName() + ";\n\tEvents: " + comp.getEventNames());
    }

}
```

Output for PrimeFaces 7.0:

```
org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@239963d8:
    defaultEvent: valueChange;
    Events: [blur, change, valueChange, click, dblclick, focus, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, mouseup, select]
org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete@72d818d1:
    defaultEvent: valueChange;
    Events: [blur, change, valueChange, click, dblclick, focus, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, mouseup, select, itemSelect, itemUnselect, query, moreText, clear]
org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable@614ddd49:
    defaultEvent: null;
    Events: [rowUnselect, colReorder, tap, rowEditInit, toggleSelect, cellEditInit, sort, rowToggle, cellEdit, rowSelectRadio, filter, cellEditCancel, rowSelect, contextMenu, taphold, rowReorder, colResize, rowUnselectCheckbox, rowDblselect, rowEdit, page, rowEditCancel, virtualScroll, rowSelectCheckbox]
```

Comment: @Kukeltje I added clarification, was late yesterday evening ^^

Comment: I added this issue to get this added to the PF Docsify site: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5086

Comment: @Melloware good idea, I'm sure this is easy to automate so PF doc will never fail to mention/describe any supported AJAX event again :)

Comment: In case of roomba I also added an answer to the possible duplicate.